# Zoom Image on ng-mouseover

Tags: html, css, angularjs, mouseover

Hi I would like to zoom my image on mouse over. I can already zoom it but what I want to have is to display the zoomed image as an overlay so that the format of my table wont be damage here is my code

```
<td ng-mouseover="style={'height':'450px','width':'800px'}" ng-mouseleave="style={'height':'50px'}"> 
     <img ng-src='{{ item.photo }}' height='50px' class="text-center" ng-style="style" />
</td>
```

How can I do that? Thanks in advance